# Unable to sort my JQGrid when 1 column has editable: true

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

That's really the gist of it.. I can set up a grid and make the columns sortable, and everything works fine.  When I throw a `select` on one of the columns, I need to make it 'editable' so it will show up, but then sorting is disabled!

```
    name: 'Stats',
    index: 'Stats',
    width: 170,
    align: "left",
    sortable: true,
    editable: true,
    edittype: 'select',
    editoptions: {
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, this stackoverflow answer made it work..

Apparently there is an issue in JQGrid when you try to sort when using editable columns.  It is explained more here:

[Issue with sorting column while editing rows inline in jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280418/issue-with-sorting-column-while-editing-rows-inline-in-jqgrid)

I find that a little bit annoying in the year since that question was answered, there is no fix in JQGrid.  However.. I can't complain.  Its free. :)

btw, the answer in that link a little dated, as I had to swap out `$th.data('events')` in the code with `$._data($th[0], "events")`

pay attention to the follow up text:

```
@Oleg, I'm trying your solution but without success, the currentHandlers is undefined in clickBinding = currentHandlers.click... Maybe you have a hint? – eklam Jul 5 at 17:20

@eklam: Which version of jQuery you use for "subclassing" event handle? If you use jQuery version 1.8 or higher you should use `$._data($th[0], "events");` instead of `$th.data('events')`. – Oleg Jul 5 at 17:48
```