# How can I configure this JQGrid column definition so the sort is performed on the listbox entry's "display" value, rather than the "key" value?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have an editable column definition that looks like this...

```
    {
        name: 'recType',           
        label: 'recType',           
        index: 'recType',                           
        width: 100, 
        fixed: true,  
        keys:  true,     
        editable: true, 
        edittype: "select",  
        editoptions: {value: rectypelist}, 
        stype: 'select',
        formatter: 'select'
    }
```

Note: "rectypelist" is a list of  **key:value** pairs...e.g.,

```
    1:apple
    4:pear
    2:orange
    3:banana
```

I need to be able to sort this column by the listbox entry's value *(i.e., which is already correctly displayed in the column)*.

As it is configured, above, the sort is performed upon the listbox entry's "key",  rather than the entry's "value" (the entry's "value" is what actually displays in the grid).

-So, therefore, when the user sorts the column they do not received the expected behavior.

**QUESTION:** How can I configure this column definition so that the sort is performed on the listbox entry's "display" value, rather than the "key" value?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Here's how I solved the issue...

Well, apparently when your column is defined as dropdown/listbox (containing rows of key:value pairs)...

like,

```
    1:rectypeA
    4:rectypeB
    2:rectypeC
    3:rectypeD
```

...then, in the column definition, you need assign a function to the "sorttype" parameter that will return the value you want to sort on... *(in this case I want to use the "value" from the "key:value" pair)*...

--Since I ***don't*** want my column sorted by the "**key**" *(i.e., this is the problem I am trying to solve!)*,  I apparently have to use a function to return the "**value**" that corresponds to the "key".

In the example, below, I've created a map called "rectypes" that contains ***key:value*** pairs.

--In the function, I simply use the "rectypes" map to extract and return the value *(associated with the "key")* that  I want used in the sort

i.e.,

```
    -
    -
    -
    {
        name: 'recType',           
        label: 'recType',           
        index: 'recType',                                               
        width: 100, 
        fixed: true,  
        keys:   true, 
        sortable:true,  
        //...the function below returns the VALUE of 
        //   the KEY:VALUE pair that is to be used for the sort
        sorttype: function (cellvalue ) {return rectypes[cellvalue];},
        editable: true, 
        edittype: "select",  
        editoptions: {value: rectypelist}, 
        stype: 'select', 
        formatter: 'select'
    },    
    -
    -
    -
```

NOTE: "cellvalue" is supplied auto-magically.   In the example I created a map called "rectypes" containing the "key:value" pairs that make it possible for me to extract and return the value that I want to be used for sorting.