# Sorting of columns when inline edit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Not sure if that is a limitation or not. not able to sort any column when inline edit is there for at least one row.

Fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/nMfaab/1

steps:

1. click Search button
2. Select one or more rows
3. Click "Change Value" button -> All selected rows should be now
   inline edit
4. Now try to Sort on any column

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   ```

   SKumar - JQGrid
       
       
       
       
       -->

   ```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery-ui-multiselect/1.13.6/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
   <style type="text/css">
       html, body { font-size: 75%; }
       #gridSearchResult {
           height: 460px;
       }
   </style>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
       $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
       $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
   </script>
   <!--<script src="http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script> -->
   <script src="https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
   <!--<script src="jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>-->
   <script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
       /*global $ */
       /*jslint eqeq: true, browser: true, plusplus: true */
       $(function () {
           "use strict";
           var $grid = $("#list"),
               gridData,
               startTime,
               measureTime = false,
               timeInterval,
               myDefaultSearch = "cn",
               getColumnIndexByName = function (columnName) {
                   var cm = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'), i, l = cm.length;
                   for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
                       if (cm[i].name === columnName) {
                           return i; // return the index
                       }
                   }
                   return -1;
               },
               modifySearchingFilter = function (separator) {
                   var i, l, rules, rule, parts, j, group, str, iCol, cmi, cm = this.p.colModel,
                       filters = $.parseJSON(this.p.postData.filters);
                   if (filters && typeof filters.rules !== 'undefined' && filters.rules.length > 0) {
                       rules = filters.rules;
                       for (i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
                           rule = rules[i];
                           iCol = getColumnIndexByName.call(this, rule.field);
                           cmi = cm[iCol];
                           if (iCol >= 0 && ((typeof (cmi.searchoptions) === "undefined" ||
                                 typeof (cmi.searchoptions.sopt) === "undefined")
                                && rule.op === myDefaultSearch) ||
                                   (typeof (cmi.searchoptions) === "object" &&
                                       $.isArray(cmi.searchoptions.sopt) &&
                                       cmi.searchoptions.sopt[0] === rule.op)) {
                               // make modifications only for the 'contains' operation
                               parts = rule.data.split(separator);
                               if (parts.length > 1) {
                                   if (typeof filters.groups === 'undefined') {
                                       filters.groups = [];
                                   }
                                   group = {
                                       groupOp: 'OR',
                                       groups: [],
                                       rules: []
                                   };
                                   filters.groups.push(group);
                                   for (j = 0, l = parts.length; j < l; j++) {
                                       str = parts[j];
                                       if (str) {
                                           // skip empty '', which exist in case of two separaters of once
                                           group.rules.push({
                                               data: parts[j],
                                               op: rule.op,
                                               field: rule.field
                                           });
                                       }
                                   }
                                   rules.splice(i, 1);
                                   i--; // to skip i++
                               }
                           }
                       }
                       this.p.postData.filters = JSON.stringify(filters);
                   }
               },
               dataInitMultiselect = function (elem) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        var $elem = $(elem), id = elem.id,
                            inToolbar = typeof id === "string" && id.substr(0,3) === "gs_";
                            options = {
                                selectedList: 2,
                                height: "auto",
                                checkAllText: "All",
                                uncheckAllText: "None",
                                noneSelectedText: "Any",
                                open: function () {
                                    var $menu = $(".ui-multiselect-menu:visible");
                                    $menu.width("auto");
                                    return;
                                }
                            };
                        if (inToolbar) {
                            options.minWidth = 'auto';
                        }
                        $elem.multiselect(options);
                        $elem.siblings('button.ui-multiselect').css({
                            width: inToolbar? "98%": "100%",
                            marginTop: "1px",
                            marginBottom: "1px",
                            paddingTop: "3px"
                        });
                    }, 50);
                };


           var date = new Date(), t = Object.prototype.toString.call(date), t1 = String(date);

           $( "#search" ).click(function() {
               var statesAsString = getStates();
               startTime = new Date();
               $grid.jqGrid({
                   datatype: 'json',
                   url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/efhbt',
                   mtype: 'GET',
                           colNames: ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'ii', 'Priority', 'Due Date', 'll', 'mm'],
                   colModel: [
                       { name: "aa", width: 200, label: "c01", frozen: true },
                       { name: "bb", width: 200, label: "c02", frozen: true },
                       { name: "cc", width: 100, label: "c03", frozen: true, search: true,
                           stype:'select', 
                               searchoptions: {
                                    sopt: ['eq','ne'],
                                    value: statesAsString,
                                    attr: {multiple: 'multiple', size: 3},
                                    dataInit: dataInitMultiselect
                                }
                       },
                       { name: "dd", width: 100, label: "c04" },
                       { name: "ee", width: 100, label: "c05" },
                       { name: "ff", label: "c06" },
                       { name: "gg", label: "c07", editable: true, stype: 'select', formatter: 'select',
                           edittype: 'select', editoptions: {
                               value: 'Select:Select;Y:Yes;N:No',
                               multiple: false
                           }
                       },
                       { name: "hh", label: "c08", editable: true, stype: 'select', formatter: 'select',
                           edittype: 'select', editoptions: {
                               value: 'Select:Select;Y:Yes;N:No',
                               multiple: false
                           }
                       },
                       { name: "ii", label: "c09", editable: true, stype: 'select', formatter: 'select',
                           edittype: 'select', editoptions: {
                               value: 'Select:Select;Y:Yes;N:No',
                               multiple: false
                           }
                       },
                       { name: "jj", label: "c10", width: 100, editable: true },
                       { name: "kk", label: "c11", width: 100, editable: true, 
                           formatter:'date', formatoptions: {newformat:'Y-m-d'}, datefmt: 'Y-m-d',
                           editoptions: {
                               size:20, 
                               dataInit: function(el){ 
                                   $(el).datepicker({
                                       dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                                       changeYear: true,
                                       changeMonth: true,
                                       showWeek: true,
                                       yearRange: '1999:+1',
                                       minDate: new Date()
                                   }); 
                               }, 
                               defaultValue: function(){ 
                                   var currentTime = new Date(); 
                                   var month = parseInt(currentTime.getMonth() + 1); 
                                   month = month <= 9 ? "0"+month : month; 
                                   var day = currentTime.getDate(); 
                                   day = day <= 9 ? "0"+day : day;
                                   var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
                                   return year+"-"+month + "-"+day; 
                               },
                               maxlength: 10
                           },
                           searchoptions: {
                               sopt: ['eq'],
                               dataInit: function (elem) {
                                   $(elem).datepicker({
                                       dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                                       changeYear: true,
                                       changeMonth: true,                            
                                       showWeek: true,
                                       showButtonPanel: true,
                                       autoclose: false,
                                       currentText: "Clear",
                                       closeText: "Filter",
                                       yearRange: '1999:+1',
                                       onSelect: function( selectedDate, inst ) {
                                           $(this).focus();
                                           var target = $(selectedDate);
                                           var inst = this._getInst(target[0]);
                                           inst.inline = true;
                                           $.datepicker._selectDateOverload(selectedDate, inst);
                                           inst.inline = false;
                                           this._updateDatepicker(inst);
                                       }
                                   }).focus(function() {
                                       var thisCalendar = $(this);
                                       $('.ui-datepicker-close').click(function() {
                                           var selectedDate = $("#gs_kk").val();
                                           setTimeout(function () {
                                               $('#list')[0].triggerToolbar();
                                           }, 100);

                                       });

                                       $('.ui-datepicker-current').click(function() {
                                           var selectedDate = $("#gs_kk").val('');
                                       });
                                   });
                               }
                           }
                       },
                       { name: "ll", label: "c12", editable: true },
                       { name: "mm", label: "c13", editable: true }
                   ],
                   cmTemplate: { width: 100, autoResizable: true },
                   rowNum: 1000,
                   records: 1000,
                   rownumWidth: 40,
                   rowList: [20, 100, 1000, 10000, "100000:All"],
                   viewrecords: true,
                   rownumbers: true,
                   toppager: false,
                   pager: false,
                   shrinkToFit: false,
                   multiselect: true,
                   editurl: 'clientArray',
                   loadonce: true,
                   width: 800,
                   height: 400,
                   onSortCol: function () {
                       startTime = new Date();
                       measureTime = true;
                   },
                   /*onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
                       var $self = $(this),
                           savedRow = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
                       if (savedRow.length > 0) {
                           $self.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRow[0].id);
                       }
                       $self.jqGrid("editRow", rowid);
                   },*/
                   loadComplete: function () {
                       if (measureTime) {
                           setTimeout(function () {
                               //alert("Total loading time: " + timeInterval + "ms");
                           }, 50);
                           measureTime = false;
                       }
                   },
                   autoencode: true,
                   caption: "Shows the performance of resizing. Make double-click on the column resizer"
               }).jqGrid("filterToolbar", {
                       beforeSearch: function () {
                           startTime = new Date();
                           measureTime = true;
                           return false; // allow filtering
                       }
               }).jqGrid("gridResize");
               $grid.jqGrid("setFrozenColumns");
           });


            timeInterval = new Date() - startTime;
            setTimeout(function () {
               // alert("Total time: " + timeInterval + "ms");
            }, 50);


           // START: Sorting even after inline editing
            $.each($('#list')[0].grid.headers, function () {
               var $th = $(this.el), i, l, clickHandler, clickHandlers = [],
                   currentHandlers = $._data($th[0], "events"),
                   clickBinding = currentHandlers.click;

               if ($.isArray(clickBinding)) {
                   for (i = 0, l = clickBinding.length; i < l; i++) {
                       clickHandler = clickBinding[i].handler;
                       clickHandlers.push(clickHandler);
                       $th.unbind('click', clickHandler);
                   }
               }
               $th.click(function () {
                   var p = $grid[0].p, savedRow = p.savedRow, j, len = savedRow.length;
                   if (len > 0) {
                       // there are rows in cell editing or inline editing
                       if (p.cellEdit) {
                           // savedRow has the form {id:iRow, ic:iCol, name:nm, v:value}
                           // we can call restoreCell or saveCell
                           //$grid.jqGrid("restoreCell", savedRow[0].id, savedRow[0].ic);
                           $grid.jqGrid("saveCell", savedRow[0].id, savedRow[0].ic);
                       } else {
                           // inline editing
                           for (j = len - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                               // call restoreRow or saveRow
                               //$grid.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRow[j].id);
                               $grid.jqGrid("saveRow", savedRow[j].id);
                           }
                       }
                   }
               });
               l = clickHandlers.length;
               if (l > 0) {
                   for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                       $th.bind('click', clickHandlers[i]);
                   }
               }
           }); 
           // END: Sorting even after inline editing


            // On Click Of Button
           $( "#Change_Value" ).click(function() {
               var v = $("#name").val();
               var myGrid = $("#list");
               var selRowIds = myGrid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow");
               //alert(selRowId.length);
               for (var i = 0; i < selRowIds.length; i++) {
                   //rowData = myGrid.jqGrid("getLocalRow", selRowIds[i]);
                   // one can uses the data here
                   myGrid.jqGrid("editRow", selRowIds[i], true);
               }
           });
       });

       function getStates() {
           var statesAsString = '';
           $.ajax({
               type    : "GET",
               url     : "https://api.myjson.com/bins/xvjhl",
               ContentType : 'json',
               cache: false,
               async: false,
               success : function (data) {
                   var len = data.length;
                   for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                       if(!(data[i] == null || data[i].toUpperCase() == 'NULL'))
                       {
                           statesAsString += data[i] + ':' + data[i]+ ';';
                       }
                       }   
                       statesAsString = statesAsString.slice(0, -1);               
               }
           })
           return statesAsString;
       }
   //]]>
   </script>
   ```

   Country: 
                                        
                           State:

   ```
                       <input type="button" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
                   </TD>
                   <TD align=right>
                       <input type="button" name="Change_Value" id="Change_Value" value="Change Priority to High" /> 
                   </TD>
               </TR>
           </TBODY>
       </TABLE>
   </div>

   <div id='gridSearchResult' style="margin-top: 10px;">
       <table id="list"></table>
   </div>
   <div style="border: 1px solid black; align: centre; margin-top: 10px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
       <TABLE width="100%">
       <TBODY>
           <TR>
               <TD align=center>
                   <input type="button" name="save" id="save" value="Save" />&nbsp;&nbsp;

                   <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
               </TD>
           </TR>
       </TBODY>
   </TABLE>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: Any help please...

Comment: Still could not figure it out. Need help please...

Comment: Fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/nMfaab/1