# free-jqgrid - sorting with inline edit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am new in this forum. I am using free-jqgrid latest version. I have a problem in sorting after inline edit. I see a similar question is answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280418/issue-with-sorting-column-while-editing-rows-inline-in-jqgrid) in older version of jqgrid and another question (not yet answered) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632946/sorting-of-columns-when-inline-edit) in recent version. Could anyone help me here.

Comment: Can anyone please help in understanding this, What does this -1 means. Does this mean it is not a right forum to ask?

Comment: You could provide some code, to let it to be answered in a better way

Comment: I am using exact same sorting code as it used in this demo: http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SortingDuringInlineOrCellEditing.htm